# Can't get Move-AzureResource working

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to move some of my resources (Azure Web Apps, Azure SQLs, Redis caches) from one resource group to another. I'm using the Azure Resource Manager PowerShell cmdlets.

Here's what I've tried:

```
PS C:\> Move-AzureResource -DestinationResourceGroupName NewResourceGroup -ResourceId "/subscriptions/someguid/resourceGroups/Default-Web-WestEurope/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/somesite"
```

Or:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureResource -ResourceName somesite | Move-AzureResource -DestinationResourceGroupName NewResourceGroup
```

Or:
just `Move-AzureResource`, hitting enter and supplying the parameters one by one.

None of the commands seems to work. They just don't do anything. No error, no output. 
When I changed the debug preference to `$DebugPreference = "Continue"` I got only the following:

```
DEBUG: 12:16:06 - MoveAzureResourceCommand begin processing with ParameterSet '__AllParameterSets'.
DEBUG: 12:16:06 - using account id 'my@account.tld'...
```

Please note that I'm able to create a new resource group (`New-AzureResourceGroup`), list resource groups (`Get-AzureResourceGroup`), list resources (`Get-AzureResource`), etc.

Note: you have to call `Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager` before you can use the cmdlets. The authentication is done by `Add-AzureAccount`.

Articles I've been referring to:

- [Moving resources between Azure Resource Groups](http://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/03/24/moving-resources-between-azure-resource-groups/)
- [Move-AzureResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986795.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Using Azure PowerShell with Azure Resource Manager](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/)
- [GitHub - Using Azure PowerShell with Azure Resource Manager](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager.md)

Comment: Having the same issue. Tried creating a new group and moving to that group - no luck either. Command not returning any response; no confirmation, no error, just shows the command prompt again.

Checked with DebugPreference as well and outputs the same. The next step should be authentication - not sure why it's not proceeding to it.

Comment: I have a suspicion that it's a bug. I'll probably submit a bug soon if I won't get any answers...

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I've found no other information as to what the problem is.

Comment: I have created an [issue on Azure PowerShell GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/379). 
I hope they'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original issue is fixed in the [0.9.4 release](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/0.9.4-June2015). I just tried and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Reading this [azure forum](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-preview-portal/suggestions/6178622-ability-to-move-resources-from-one-resource-group) it looks like they have implemented the cmdlet but not all resources support being moved yet.

> We have released a new powershell cmdlet to move resources across resource groups. Not all resources have support yet, but the "main" ones do like hosted services, virtual machines & storage accounts.

Looking back at the example I was following, this does only use VM's. So based on this I think websites aren't supported yet. That fact that no error or warning is returned for unsupported resources is a bit poor.

Comment: Thx for you answer! I've added my votes to the issue. Hope it'll get addressed asap :)

Answer (score 2):

Though not all resources are currently supported, I understand the current version - 0.9.1 - does have a bug which means that even a supported resource may not be moved with the symptoms as seen by the author of the question. I understand this is being worked on for the next release, but in the interim (as a temp. work around) the previous powershell cmdlets release of 2 versions ago should work fine. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases

Comment: Thanks! I tried version 0.8.16 and it behaves a little bit better. It gives me a confirmation message "Are you sure you want to move resource(s) into the resource goup named...?" Then it seems to do "something" because when I try to instantly re-run the command it say "The resource group '...' is being updated and cannot perform this operation."  But when it's done nothing is changed. So I guess webapps are not supported yet as @Youngs suggests.

Answer (score 1):

FYI. To move a VM using Move-AzureResourceGroup you need to move the containing cloud service and all its VMs at the same time. For example:

```
Get-AzureResource -ResourceGroupName OriginalResourceGroup | where { $_.ResourceType -match 'Microsoft.ClassicCompute' } | Move-AzureResource -DestinationResourceGroupName NewResourceGroup
```

By default, the resources in a cloud service are put in a resource group with the same name as the DNS name of the cloud service.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. But I've been trying to move azure web app.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Azure PowerShell Version 1.0 has trouble moving over web apps from one Resource Group to another. If you follow the instrctions below, you will be able to move the web app over via powershell.

Download Azure PowerShell Version 1. The below instructions only work for this version. Type the commands below in order.

```
1) **Login-AzureRmAccount** (a login window will pop up asking for your azure credentials, type them in)
2) **Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "NameOfResourceGroup" -ResourceName "WebAppName"** (if you are moving over a website, you will see 2 files, you need the one that is a resource type of Microsoft.Web/sites)
3) **Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "NameOfResourceGroup" -ResourceName "WebAppName" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites"**
4) Assign value 3 to a variable of your name choice. I Chose $a, so **$a = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "NameOfResourceGroup" -ResourceName "WebAppName" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites"**
5) **Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroup "DestinationResourceGroup" -ResourceId $a.ResourceId**
6) It will ask you if you are sure type "Y" and hit enter.
```